# less-loader module build fail with ~ import

Tags: css, webpack, less

I'm trying to compile less into css using webpack

I get a module build failed for less-loader

```
 near lines:
   /* this is a comment */
   @import '~/styles/obj.less';
```

I don't want to remove the ~ and I've read that webpack 4 thinks this is in the node modules folder? I also don't want to add the .less from the import statement. I'm trying to understand how to use the tilde without breaking the build and looking for a solution.

This is my webpack config rules section

```
    config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.less$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
    use: [
        {
            loader: "style-loader"
        },

        {
            loader: "css-loader",

        },
        {
            loader: "less-loader", // compiles Less to CSS
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a slash after the tilde (~), otherwise it resolves into current folder.

So assuming you have a module called "styles" in your node_modules, then you need:

```
@import '~styles/obj.less';
```